# How to Create a new Json using array c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I need to create the following JSON:

```
[
    {
      "Name": [
         {
           "First Name": "Adam"
         },
         {
           "Last Name": "Smith"
         }
      ]
    }
]
```

Please help as I have tried everything on here and on json.net

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is what i have from a json and like to rewrite it to a new json with the same structure, although it does look odd, but surly one should be able to write what ever json using these tools !!?? as long as it is a valid json !!?

Comment: well I would suggest it is invalid JSON as this is a collection on NAMES which should be a consistent object type. Maybe this might help http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: regardless of the content i can assure you that the structure is valid

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you edit the post to add source code of what you have tried.

Comment: @J.Piquard i have tried everything there is here and everywhere and don't have a code which is why i am here with this post

Comment: If you have no source code, take a look to that ["Blog - Json.NET Examples"](https://surajdeshpande.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/json-net-examples/)

Comment: If you have no source code, take a look at the help center and learn how to ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @CareyGregory- I did explain that I had tried every source code there is without any luck, which is why i had to post the question, while at the same time the question was how to get to the given json and what would have been the point to post a source code that wont work !!?? but thanks for your advice, as i shall remember if i have any questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... it is funny how things work once you know how its done :) and here for those who may have the same problem, this is the way to do it :

```
JObject myObject = 
       new JObject(
           new JProperty("Name",
                      new JArray(
                                new JObject(
                                new JProperty("First Name", "Adam")),
                                new JObject(
                                new JProperty("Last Name", "Smith")))));

JArray myArray = new JArray
myArray.Add(myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED ANSWER: Removed old answer explaining what I thought the issue was with the JSON in the question. Changed to build C# objects that could create the JSON string above, haven't tried this but I think it should work:

Here are the C# classes:

```
public class Name
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public List<Name> Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create the name objects in the RootObject:

```
var myRootObj = new RootObject();
myRootObj.Name = new List<Name>();

var firstNameObj = new Name() { FirstName = "Adam" };
var secondNameObj = new Name() { LastName = "Smith" };

myRootObj.Name.Add(firstNameObject);
myRootObj.Name.Add(secondNameObject);
```

Now lets convert this object to JSON:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myRootObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
                            new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                            }););
```

I haven't tried this but I think it should create your JSON string, such as below:

```
    {
      "Name": [
         {
           "First Name": "Adam"
         },
         {
           "Last Name": "Smith"
         }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: you are right but i have this json the way i have written and just need to reconstruct it !!?

Comment: thank you very much for the link as it seems to be a very handy tool for the future use but unfortunately not for the on hand problem

Comment: @Mehrdad_gh - I have re-written the answer and I think it should help you convert a C# object to your JSON type. Not checked it, but I have corrected some of the errors in the C# sample above. Let us know if it is what you are looking for

Comment: @cododromo- thank you again this is the outcome from your code, here is what i got when using it: [
  {
    "First Name": "Adam"
  },
  {
    "Last Name": "Smith"
  }
] and the "Name" jarray is missing from the result !!?

Comment: @Mehrdad_gh - I think the bit that is missing is to make NAME in ROOTOBJECT a JsonProperty. I have edited the code above to do this, give that a try. If it works can you accept the answer so others know this works for this question. Thanks.

Comment: thank you ever so much, you have just been a great life saver :)

Comment: @cododromo- it looks as if there is a hiccup as the whole produced json is JObject while this object should be part an array !!??

Comment: @Mehrdad_gh - can you paste the JSON you get back from the code above, you need to add the outer '[ ]' yourself. Remember, after Serializing the object the 'var json' is just a C# string. So in C# that would be: json = '[' + json + ']';

Comment: @cododromo- i hope you don't mean to add it manually :)) and here is the json from the above code :{
  "Name": [
    {
      "First Name": "Adam"
    },
    {
      "Last Name": "Smith"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @Mehrdad_gh - there might be a way to add the [] via code but I don't know. My manual method, far from perfect will get the job done.

Comment: @cododromo- :) thank you once more, i hope i will find the way to add the array (not manually !!? :) )but still your code is very helpful and i should come with result if i find the way :) Cheers